# Model not binding in asp core 2.1 from angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-2.1

This is my Model and asp core functionality

```js
public class RuleActionModel
    {

        public string RuleData { get; set; }

        public string ActionData { get; set; }

    }
    
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Create(string objectId, string applicationId, [FromBody]RuleActionModel ruleActionData)
        {
          string ruleData= ruleActionData.RuleData;
        }
```

This is my angular code

```js
var objectid="123";
var applicationid="1";
$scope.ruleActionData={};
ruleActionData.ruleData="{'name':'one'}";
ruleActionData.actionData="[{'name':'one'}]";
$scope.CreateRule = function () {

    $http.post('/api/Rule/Create?objectId='+objectid+'&applicationId='+applicationid, $scope.ruleActionData).then(function (response) {
       
    });
};
```

In the above code model not binding, but remaining query fields are bind.I tried with FromBody and without FromBody also. This code working in mvc with angularjs, but not in asp core. How to bind model properties from angularjs to asp core 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[FromQuery]** attribute if you pass parameters in query string